# Java FileWriter only writing first line

Tags: java, swing, filewriter

I am working on a Java application that has a JTextArea for users to input text. It can be any amount of lines, however I am running into a problem with my FileWriter, where it's only saving the first line of any input. I've never used Swing or FileWriter before at all, so I may be getting this quite wrong, but here's my code:

```
FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(lastSavedFile);
        details.write(fw);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.err.println("Error saving file");
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fw != null) {
            try {
                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                System.err.println("Error closing writer");
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the "details" function doing? the problem might be there...

Comment: The entire solution is in the class that details references (which cannot be determined from the code snippet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try flushing the FileWriter before closing it in the finally block. 
.

```
.
if (fw != null) 
{
   try 
   {
       fw.flush();
       fw.close();
   } catch (IOException exception) 
   {
       System.err.println("Error closing writer");
       exception.printStackTrace();
   }
}
.
.
```

I agree with @Yishai ... And if possible then give the use of details function. This would help others to answer it.

Comment: If `fw.close()` doesn't do a `flush` itself, then there is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use the constructor like this:
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("lastsavedfilee.txt",true);